# Update in Bootstrap datepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use bootstrap datepicker when i try to call the date function it's not working can anyone help me please.

```
    var date ="1/3/2015";
    $( '.input-daterange .from-date' ).datepicker( {
            autoclose:true,
            endDate : new Date(date),
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    } );


    date =(dat.getMonth()+1) +"/" +dat.getDate() + "/"+ dat.getFullYear();
    $( '.input-daterange .from-date' ).click(function(){
        $( '.input-daterange .from-date' ).datepicker('update');
    });
```

Onload it works fine with this date "1/3/2015" afterwards trying the update the variable date with current-date it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.from-date').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2008,9,03) );
```

You have to put there data object like on an example

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`$( '.input-daterange .from-date' ).datepicker('update',new Date());`